# OnlyDigits Function in Criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba

My database has a job number field that consists of year+month/serialnumber+type.  There can be multiple jobs with the same job number:

201812/6Door
201812/6Stair
201812/6Wardrobe

When the user wants to change the date of any/all of these records I want all 201812/6 jobs to show in a form.

I have successfully used the OnlyDigits function below to pull only numbers from the text field: OnlyDigits(JobNumber) = 2018126.  But I can't figure out how to filter the form to show all jobs containing 2018126.

I have tried using this query but get an error saying expression typed incorrectly or is too complex.

```
SELECT onlydigits(jobnumber) AS JobNumberDigits, tbldelivery.DelDateDoors, tbldelivery.Lag, tbldelivery.ProductionDate, tbldelivery.OrderNumber, tbldelivery.JobNumber
FROM tbldelivery
WHERE (((onlydigits(jobnumber))=OnlyDigits([Forms]![tblDelivery]![JobNumber])));
```

I also tried using a where expression in Docmd.OpenForm but that didn't work either.  Can anyone suggest how I use this function to filter?

```
Public Function OnlyDigits(ByVal pInput As String) As String
    Static objRegExp As Object

    If objRegExp Is Nothing Then
        Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With objRegExp
            .Global = True
            .Pattern = "[^\d]"
        End With
    End If
    OnlyDigits = objRegExp.Replace(pInput, vbNullString)
End Function
```

Comment: If the function does what you say it does AND the fields contain what you think they contain, then the SQL looks reasonable so there should be no problem.  If it does not work, then you need to **inspect each part separately**.  This is a debugging exercise for which you have not provided enough information to be useful here.  There are so many ways to debug this that it is almost not worth listing the possibilities: use the VBA immediate window; execute a query without a WHERE clause, but with individual expressions in the SELECT list so that you can see the values; etc.

Comment: Although it may not be the only cause of problems, you should consider NULL values.  How does `OnlyDigits()` handle NULL values?

Comment: If the error says "typed incorrectly", that is the key... check the datatypes of all function parameters of `OnlyDigits()`.  Check the data type of the `JobNumber` control on the form.  It is likely a variant that contains a string value or Null.  Check the data type of the jobnumber field.  Is this field nullable?  Are all of these data types compatible?

Comment: I count 10 parens in the WHERE statement. As far as I can see they do match. Edit question to post the OnlyDigits() function. I would not use WHERE clause in query. Instead of dynamic parameterized query, I would use WHERE argument of DoCmd.OpenForm or if form already open, set Filter and FilterOn properties.

Comment: I have added the onlydigits function above so you can see how NULLs are treated etc.  
The resulting format in my query is text and I have tried the answer below but I get a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the parameter to free Access from guessing:

```
PARAMETERS 
    [Forms]![tblDelivery]![JobNumber] Text;
SELECT 
    OnlyDigits(JobNumber) AS JobNumberDigits, 
    tbldelivery.DelDateDoors, 
    tbldelivery.Lag, 
    tbldelivery.ProductionDate, 
    tbldelivery.OrderNumber, 
    tbldelivery.JobNumber
FROM 
    tbldelivery
WHERE 
    OnlyDigits(JobNumber)=OnlyDigits([Forms]![tblDelivery]![JobNumber]);
```

or:

```
WHERE 
    OnlyDigits(CStr(Nz(JobNumber, 0)))=OnlyDigits([Forms]![tblDelivery]![JobNumber]);
```

Comment: I have tried this in my query but get a type mismatch error.  The query shows the JobNumberDigits as a text field.  Do I need to change the result from the onlydigits function to something other than a string?

Comment: Perhaps your JobNumber contains Null values. Seee edited answer, please.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for your help!